# SSL_connect results in SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL with WSAENOTCONN on Windows

Tags: c++, sockets, ssl, tcp, openssl

I try to set SSL connection on Windows with OpenSSL. My steps follow:

1. Create TCP socket BIO.
2. Connect to server with TCP.
3. Add this BIO to SSL instance.
4. Upgrade connection to SSL.

However, when I try to call `SSL_connect` with BIO that for sure recently connected to TCP socket, I receive SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL with WSAENOTCONN on Windows.

My code follows.

```
this->TcpSocket = BIO_new(BIO_s_connect());
BIO_set_nbio(this->TcpSocket, 1);
BIO_set_conn_hostname(this->TcpSocket, hostname);
BIO_set_conn_port(this->TcpSocket, port);
int connectionResult;
while ((connectionResult = BIO_do_connect(this->TcpSocket)) <= 0 && BIO_should_retry(this->TcpSocket))
{
        auto retryType = BIO_retry_type(this->TcpSocket);
        if (retryType & BIO_FLAGS_READ != 0
            || retryType & BIO_FLAGS_WRITE != 0)
        {
            auto handle = BIO_get_fd(this->TcpSocket, NULL);
            fd_set handles;
            handles.fd_count = 1;
            handles.fd_array[0] = handle;
            timeval timeout;
            timeout.tv_sec = seconds;
            timeout.tv_usec = 0;
            if (retryType & BIO_FLAGS_READ != 0)
                select(handle + 1, &handles, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
            else
                select(handle + 1, NULL, &handles, NULL, &timeout);
        }
        else
            Thread::Sleep(50);
}
this->SslContext = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
SSL_CTX_set_verify(this->SslContext, SSL_VERIFY_NONE, NULL);
this->SslSocket = SSL_new(this->SslContext);
SSL_set_bio(this->SslSocket, this->TcpSocket, this->TcpSocket);
int sslConnectResult;
while ((sslConnectResult = SSL_connect(this->SslSocket)) == -1)
{
    auto now = time(NULL);
    int sslConnectErrorCode = SSL_get_error(this->SslSocket, sslConnectResult);
    switch (sslConnectErrorCode)
    {
    case SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:
    case SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE:
        if (now >= deadline)
            throw SocketTimeoutException();
        else
            this->WaitForTcpSocket(deadline - now);
        break;
    case SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:
        {
            auto err = GetLastError();
            this->RaiseOpenSSLException();
        }
        break;
    default:
        this->RaiseOpenSSLException();
    }
}
```

What is reason of the error? I understand that it means that client is disconnected from server. But I don't understand why. I have good Internet connection, and server also is stable, so it is unlikely that the reason in network connectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your TCP connect loop is not taking into account if `BIO_do_connect()` fails and `BIO_should_retry()` returns false.  Your loop will stop in that condition and you will not have a connection, but you attempt to activate SSL anyway, which could cause the `WSAENOTCONN` error.

Try something more like this instead:

```
do
{
    connectionResult = BIO_do_connect(this->TcpSocket);
    if (connectionResult > 0)
        break;

    if (!BIO_should_retry(this->TcpSocket))
        throw SocketException();

    auto retryType = BIO_retry_type(this->TcpSocket);
    if (retryType & (BIO_FLAGS_READ | BIO_FLAGS_WRITE))
    {
        auto handle = BIO_get_fd(this->TcpSocket, NULL);
        fd_set handles;
        FD_ZERO(&handles);
        FD_SET(handle, &handles);
        timeval timeout;
        timeout.tv_sec = seconds;
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;
        if (retryType & BIO_FLAGS_READ)
            selectResult = select(handle + 1, &handles, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
        else
            selectResult = select select(handle + 1, NULL, &handles, NULL, &timeout);

        if (selectResult < 0)
            throw SocketException();

        if (selectResult == 0)
            throw SocketTimeoutException();
    }
    else
        Thread::Sleep(50);
}
while (true);
```